# htaccess redirect to www, subfolder and hide folder name

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all requests, even non-www, to

```
www.site.com/public
```

but hide 'public' from the URL.

This code handles the www portion

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

and this redirects to /public

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

How can I combine them?

Comment: What you have now will silently rewrite things into `public/` but if a browser requests `/public/something` do you also need to redirect them away from public to `/something` (after which the silent rewrite takes place)?

Comment: So, if a browser requests `http://example.com/public/something`, should the address bar actually change to `http://example.com/something`?

Comment: Yes, the silent rewrite should be there all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you access to VirtualHost ? If yes, you can set `DocumentRoot`.

Something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/public"
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

And you don't need to do this with .htaccess. It is more clean solution.

Comment: It doesn't. It handles www correctly, but in non-www case /public/ is visible in the URL. I ended up changing the document root as you suggested.